# Using Ajax in Django to display time of day every second

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am looking for a simple example of how to display current time on a a page in a django project.  I have tried searching and have come up with the following (which does not update unless I refresh the page):

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from garageMonitor.views import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url('time', time, name="time"),
)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def time(request):
  now = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())

  time_dict = {"Time":now}
  return render_to_response('time.html', {'time': time_dict})
```

Here is time.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/static/garageMonitor/scripts/refreshTime.js">
window.onload = refreshTime;
</script>
<table id="test"><tbody>
<tr>
{% include "testing.html" %}
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Here is testing.html:

```
{% for label, value in temperature.items %}
      <td >{{ label }}</td>
      <td>{{ value }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my refreshTime.js:

```
function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url monitor-test %}',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#test').html(data);
        }
        setInterval("refreshTime()", 1000);
    });
}

$(function(){
    refresh();
});
```

I'd appreciate any help please.

I looked at the code in the console.  It is complaining about the line:

```
$(function(){
```

(it does not like the "$")

Comment: Where is the refreshTime function?

Comment: Good catch trpt4him.  I changed the code to the above, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ajax seems overkill here. Why not output the time directly in Javascript, leaving out the server completely?

Comment: Are you using the javascript console under developer tools in your browser?  That's the first place I'd check to see if the javascript itself is erroring.  Now that you've changed it, I don't see a `refresh` function anywhere yet you call it from `setTimeout`...?

Comment: Daniel, your point is well made, but eventually I will be doing something other than update time (refresh images and status from the server's database.)  At this point, I am just trying to understand how to make the concept work.

Comment: I had changed my code (but no the post) to update the call to refreshTime() (instead of refresh()) from setTimeout().  The code in the post matches mine now.  I looked at the console as trpt4him suggested and it doesn't like dollar on the line:$(function(){

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

You also need jquery.  Add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` before your other script block in the html.

See documentation on setTimeout and setInterval: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Change the javascript to this:

```
function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url monitor-test %}',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#test').html(data);
        }
    });
}

$(function(){
    setInterval(refresh, 1000);
});
```

or maybe this would be better:

```
function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url monitor-test %}',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#test').html(data);
            setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
        }
    });
}

$(function(){
    refresh();
});
```

Comment: Good catch (but still not working).  I changed the javascript to the code above.

Comment: @jordanthompson did you delete your browser cache? Also, are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: I have cleared the browser cache (no difference) and the error I am getting is
"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined:
  on) @ refreshTime.js:11"

function refreshTime() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url time %}',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#test').html(data);
            setTimeout(refreshTime, 1000);
        }
    });
}

offending line >>>>> $(function(){      <<<< offending line
    refreshTime();
});

Comment: Is it really this hard?  perhaps I'll just use the html refresh tag and do the entire page.  Not pretty, but it will work :-(

Comment: @jordanthompson You need to include jquery.  Look at my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this, is a default tag in django.

```
    <ul class="sidebar-stats">
        <li class="margin left right">
            <h5>{% now "j F Y H:i" %}</h5>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: thanks, for the default tag, Paulo, but my goal is to be able to update other items in my page later (time is just a "simple" example.)

Answer (score 0):

user1132959 was spot on! I needed to add:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

I had some issues with the number of times per cycle the page was being updated.  I think this may have been because of cache, but I am not sure.
Here is what I have now that seems to be working.

**refreshTime.js:**

```
function refreshTime() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '{% url time %}',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log("success function called");
      $('#test').html(data);
    }
  });
}


$( document ).ready(function () {
  console.log("setting interval");
      setTimeout(refreshTime,1000);
});
```

**time.html:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/garageMonitor/scripts/refreshTime.js"></script>

<table id="test">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      {% include "testing.html" %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url('time', time, name="time"),
)
```

**views.py:**

```
def time(request):
  now = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())

  time_dict = {"Time":now}
  return render_to_response('time.html', {'time': time_dict})
```

I really hope this helps someone else get to the end of their rainbow faster than I did.

thanks to all who helped me!

Comment: I spoke too soon.  It is updating, but it refreshes about 15 times/second!  I have the time set to 5000 (should be 5 seconds...)

Comment: Looks like it is recursively calling itself (the number of refreshes doubles every time it is called.)

Comment: I thought I had this licked, but it is behaving strangely.  If I leave the function call to look like: $(document).ready(function () {
It seems to increase the number of times refreshTime() is called.  When I put it to be $(document).load(function () {
and I refresh the page, it works fine (called every second) until I refresh again, then it stops updating.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Django to do this - just HTML and JavaScript.

In your time.html file, use the following to display current time (updating every second):

```
<span id="time">

<script>
    function GetTime(){
    var dt = new Date();
    document.getElementByID("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
    }
    setInterval(GetTime,1000);
</script>
```